# CSS Grid has too much space between rows

Tags: css, css-grid

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz0of.jpg)

I want to create an image gallery which sits just below a paragraph of text and is centred.  My grid has meant that the rows are really far apart.

```
    /* PP Gallery */
.ppgallery {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-gap: 15px;
 margin-top: 500px;
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-right: 80px;
}

img {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 4;
 
}
```

Comment: Reduce margin-top to something less

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1):

The grid-gap property defines the size of the gap between the rows and columns in a grid layout.Reduce value of grid-gap.
Also Reduce Margin-top in your CSS file.

```css
/* PP Gallery */
.ppgallery {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-gap: 5px;     /*Reduce Grid-gap value*/
 margin-top: 100px; /*Reduce Margin-top*/
 margin-left: 80px;
 margin-right: 80px;
}

img {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 4;
 
}
```